# Building a Raspberry Pi Smart Home

Tags: raspberry-pi2

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-08-04-tutorial-building-raspberry-pi-smart-home-part-1/

hi,
i'm building the pi-house smart home(i'm totally new to python and JavaScript)
all what i'm doing that i'm following tutorial and it worked 100% well!

but tutorials are separated!! using temperature and humidity .py with a pubnub key then use light control .py with the same pubnub key and run both of them it will not work!!

can I i do both of them work at the same time ? and add led for the door light?
please share if you have a ready python or .js where everything is working!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what help you need? It sounds like you're asking us to write a lot of the project for you.

Comment: https://github.com/pubnub/pi-house/tree/gh-pages/python

Comment: there are 2 .py: 
pwm-led-gpio.py 
temp-hum.py
those 2 .py I want them to be ONE .py so it works well with one pubnub key

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy and paste the code from one file into another. Simply copy the code from one file, go to the end of the other, hit enter 5 times and paste the code.